# best language to learn for windows 10

Tags: windows

I am an amateur Java programmer.I also know Python and HTML basics.I`m recently interested in the  new windows 10.I just want you professionals to suggest me a language to start to become a windows developer.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry this question is very off-topic for StackOverflow. Acceptable questions include the possibility of an objective answer, which this does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't really conform to StackOverflow question format (since its opinion based), but I will answer it anyway.

From my personal experience windows developers mainly use .NET languages (ASP.NET, C#, Visual Basic) although Windows 10 has support for these to use the full potential of Windows 10 you would use C++.

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)  is one of the only IDE's to take windows 10 to its full advantage.

Since MSVS 2015 has all the templates for Windows 10 apps, you can create desktop and mobile applications with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Learn .Net languages and framework.

Try C#...
it is very similar to Java and in your case you can learn it easier.

the whole windows is based on .net technologies and it's related languages.

Good luck.